# Can I extract the body of an email message using Automator without an AppleScript?

Tags: email, automator

I want to build a system where all emails that are sent to a specific folder are added to a Devon Think Pro Office database for archiving/searching.

There is an add-in from the DTP folks that will allow me to add a given email to the DTP inbox on a case-by-case basis, but that is not modifiable.

I have not used AppleScript before, and do not want to learn it to do this one thing at the moment. (time constraints)

Thanks for looking

Comment: The simple answer is No. Unless you find a third party Automator Action.

Comment: Thanks fir the reply, markhunte. It's what I thought through my searching, but I hoped that I might be wrong. I have not found a third party Automator Action that will do this automagically.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a script or Automator for that.

Click on the email of interest and use the shift+cmd+s

That will bring up a window where you can now save that email as plain text in a location of your choice.

You could set up a Rules in Mac mail to get it better organized in a single folder for example.

If you want the system to find (filter) the emails and save as plain text and do that automatically for you then you need Automator and a script.

Comment: Thanks, Buscar. The thing is that I want to automate this, as you point out in the last sentence.

Comment: ok, no problem lets use Automator+Script for that than---this comment will self destruct in 1 day.

Comment: I need a bumper sticker that says SHIT-COMMAND-S :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but still only (* Catalina era) if you use "Run JavaScript" (or Shell Script) instead of "Run AppleScript".

Using the "Run JavaScript" option, a complete download-email-bodies automator recipe can look like this:

```
* Get Specified Mail Items
    [mailbox "Important" of account "Google"]

* Filter Mail Messages
    [Date Received] [is today]

* Run JavaScript
    function run(input, parameters) {
        return input.map(m => m.content());
    }

* New Text File
```

(You'd presumably tuck on your own actions at the end, instead of saving them all to a text file.)